# Pass style from string format HTML

Tags: html, angular, styles, progress-bar

I would like to passing  parameter in  `[[ style="width:{{item.number}}" ]]`

not DOM pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with ngStyle like this:

```html
<div [ngStyle]="{'width.px': someVariable }"></div>
```

Comment: it's work. but i change my code to 
style.width ="{{ item.value}}%" . same value.

thank you so much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
            <div
                    class="progress-bar bg-danger"
                    role="progressbar"
                    style="width:50%"
                    aria-valuenow="50"
                    aria-valuemin="0"
                    aria-valuemax="100"
            ></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
style.width ="{{ customer.type_value }}%"
```